# Переклад з російської "божья коровка"

Tags: переклад, from-russian

В школі на уроках біології нас вчили, що правильно і "сонечко", і "божа корівка".

"Божа корівка" схоже на кальку з російської назви.
Зараз знайшла інформацію ([Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0)), що правильно комаху називати лише "Сонечка". 
Разом з тим чула назву комахи *Бедрик, Зозулька, Петрик*. Чи можна називати комаху цими словами чи правильно лише *Сонечко*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По-перше, не всі слова, які ви використовуєте в усному мовленні, мають бути словниковими. Діалектизми цілком прийнятні у розмові й у приватних дописах будь-де. Так само вони прийнятні у публікаціях, якщо мова йде про якусь конкретну місцевість чи від мешканця такої місцевості.

По-друге:

1. І ["Словарь української мови: в 4-х тт. / За ред. Б. Грінченка.", і "Жайворонок В. В. Знаки української етнокультури: Словник-довідник."](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA) знають слово "бедрик". Користуйтеся цим словом без вагань.
2. [Російсько-український словник сталих виразів 1959р. (І. О. Вирган, М. М. Пилинська)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%97%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) і [Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%97%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) знають слово "зозулька" у значенні "сонечко", користуйтеся ним без вагань.
3. [Російсько-український академічний словник 1924–33рр. (А. Кримський, С. Єфремов)](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on) знає слово "петрик" у значенні "сонечко", користуйтеся ним без вагань.
4. [Жайворонок В. В. Знаки української етнокультури: Словник-довідник. — К.: Довіра, 2006. — С. 46.](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) знає словосполучення "божа корівка" у потрібному значенні, але старіших джерел знайти не можу, тож користуйтеся цим словосполученням з пересторогою.

Задля уникнення непорозумінь можете просто у дужках біля всіх цих розмовних слів писати щось на кшталт: (сонечко) або (/посилання на словник/).

Answer (score 5):

## Як називають цю комаху в Україні

Умовно-найвідоміші назви (комбінація даних на основі [словників на R2U](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=rus&highlight=on) і [Facebook-сторінки «Чиста мова»](//www.facebook.com/chystamova/photos/a.309176152571835.1073741828.303942943095156/507541082735340/)):

- **со́нечко**;
- **серде́нько**;
- **зозу́лька** (**зазуля**);
- **бе́дрик**, **бе́здрик**, **пе́трик**;
- **боже телятко** — зокрема в «Російсько-українському словнику сталих виразів» І. О. Виргана і М. М. Пилинської (1959);
- **бабару́на**, **бабри́ська** (**бобруна**, **брушка**) — галицьке;
- **па́ворожка**.

Ще варіанти, знайдені власноруч:

- **катеринка**
  <sub>Світлана Китова, «Полотняний літопис України: семантика орнаменту українського рушника», Черкаси, «Брама», 2003, 224 с. — [сторінка 135](//books.google.com/books?id=Z_g2AAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22): *«Божа корівка (бедрик, сонечко, катеринка)»*;</sub>
- **оленка**
  <sub>Іван Губка, «Дорогою боротьби (переможні бої УПА)», Львів, ВФ «Афіша», 2005, 632 с. — [перша виноска на сторінці 51](//books.google.com/books?id=J5QhAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA+%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%22): *«Зазуля (божа корівка, сонечко, бедрик, оленка) — за повір'ями, райська комаха, яка літає до неба і передає Богові від людей прохання і приносить відповідь»*;</sub>
- **че́чір**
  <sub>[«Етимологічний словник української мови: в 7 томах»](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm), том 6, ст. 315: *«[че́чір] (ент.) „сонечко, Coccinella L.“ Нед»*;</sub>
- **щедрик**, **коханнячко**, **рябушок**, **рябушка**, **коровиця**
  <sub>«Українська діалектна морфологія», Київ, «Наукова думка», 1969, 198 с. — [3-я виноска на сторінці 54](//books.google.com/books?id=fdk_AAAAIAAJ&q=%22%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BA%22): *«Бе́дрик — поширена в західнополіських говорах назва комахи Coccinella, що відома також тут як бездрик, петрик, щедрик, сонечко, коханнячко, зозулька, рябушок, рябушка, коровиця, божа корівка і т. д.»*.</sub>

І до речі, **божа корівка** теж згадується:

- У трьох попередніх джерелах.
- «Дохристиянські вірування українського народу: історично-релігійна монографія», Вінніпег, накладом видавничої комісії при товаристві «Волинь», «Товариство Волинь», 1965, 424 с. — [сторінка 74](//books.google.com/books?id=LpMcAAAAMAAJ&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%22+%22%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0%22): *«Сонечко чи Божа корівка, коли посадити на руку, злітає в тому напрямі, куди дівчина заміж піде»*.
- Георгій Булашев, «Український народ у своїх легендах, релігійних поглядах та віруваннях: космогонічні українські народні погляди та вірування», Київ, «Довіра», 1992, 414 с. — [сторінка 397](//www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%89%D0%B5+%D0%B4%D0%BE+%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0+%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BE%D1%97+%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B8%22): *«З усіх інших комах на Україні ставляться з повагою ще до сонечка (бедрика, божої корівки) (Coccinella)»*. Ця книга також наводить легенду, можливу, пов'язану з походженням назви *божа корівка* (її легко знайти в інтернеті за словами «й почав орати чотирма парами волів», зокрема [тут](//history.vn.ua/book/mifiukraini/32.html)):

  > <sub>Тоді Господь створив невелику людину, звичайну, таку, як ми. Виїхав цей невеличкий чоловік з погоничами у поле й почав орати чотирма парами волів. Прийшов великий чоловік, «король», забрав людей і волів у кишеню, пішов до Бога й питає: «Що це, Господи, за корівки такі?» — «Не займай їх, — рече Господь, — це люди такі будуть, а вам зараз смерть настане».</sub>

Іще Іван Верхратский у книзі «Нові знадоби номенклятури і термінольогії природописної, народної, збирані між людом» (Львів, 1908, 84 с.) на сторінці 29 наводить такий перелік:
[image]

## Статус різних назв

Нормативні:

- **сонечко** — нормативне ([згідно зі «Словником української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/sonechko));
- **божа корівка** — нормативне ([згідно зі «Словником української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=44177&page=1398)).

Оцю назву словники містять, але відносять до іншої комахи:

- *оленка* — нормативне для Epicometis hirta ([згідно зі «Словником української мови» в 11 томах](http://sum.in.ua/s/olenka)), що є [бронзівкою волохатою](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B7%D1%96%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0) або її підвидом.

Інших назв сучасні тлумачні словники навіть не знають, тож найімовірніше всі вони діалектичні (різного рівня поширення) або застарілі — що однак не є перепоною для використання їх у тому оточенні, яке Вас зрозуміє.